# Speed up copy and paste loops in VBScript

Tags: performance, loops, vbscript

I have been trying to speed up the following code. Basically, I need to copy cells in Excel down to the next filled cell. However, on a file which is only 100 rows long, it takes nearly 10 seconds to complete. This could be problematic when worksheet is a thousand rows or more long. I have researced this as best I can. The code I have is something patched together from what I have found here and other places.

I am a neophyte programmer, so my questions are:
How do I speed this process up?
Why is it so slow?
How does (better code) work more efficiently?

```
' *****Copy data down in columns A and B*****
    'Copy data in column A until next cell with a value, then get that value and copy on...
Set objWorksheet = objExcel.Worksheets(1)
    objWorksheet.Activate
Set objRange = objWorksheet.UsedRange
    objRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Activate
    intLastRow = objExcel.ActiveCell.Row
For k = 3 to intLastRow
    If objExcel.Cells(k, 1).Value = "" Then
        Set objRangeCopy = objExcel.Cells(k - 1, 1)
        objRangeCopy.Copy
        set objRangePaste = objExcel.Cells(k, 1)
        objRangePaste.Value = objRangeCopy
    End If
Next
    'Do the same with Column B
For k = 3 to intLastRow
    If objExcel.Cells(k, 2).Value = "" Then
        Set objRangeCopy = objExcel.Cells(k - 1, 2)
        objRangeCopy.Copy
        set objRangePaste = objExcel.Cells(k, 2)
        objRangePaste.Value = objRangeCopy
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Why copy/paste? Why not just retrieve the _contents_ of the cell and assign it to the cells below? You can even do it in one call (`Range("A3:A100").Value = "Test"`). Or is it a formula that needs to update? If so, you could determine the range that needs to be filled and use the Fill Down feature.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look like you're copying and pasting at all. You're just copying. =) Remove the `objRangeCopy.Copy` statements and it should work much faster.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. For the first reply, I can't set the entire range, because the files have randomly spaced values in column A, which need to be filled down to the next value. I will research more on the Fill Down feature.  However, the second method worked well. Looking at it, I guess setting the variable negates the need to copy the value.

Comment: You can still determine the empty range first (even if it is random) and then assign a value to that determined range in one step. Might be faster than assigning to the individual cells in that range. Just something to keep in mind if you're looking to improve performance.